# how to move cluster resources asynchronously

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

I try to switchover a failover cluster. The script below works just fine, but it's running in a loop and takes app. 3 min.
When using the FailoverCluster GUI, I'm selecting all services, right mouse click "move" and it runs asynchronously under 1 min. How can it be done with PowerShell?

```
$clusterGroups = Get-ClusterGroup | where{$_.state -eq "online" -and $_.name -match "SQL Server" }

foreach ($group in $clusterGroups)
{
    $currentNode = $group.OwnerNode
    Write-Host "Moving $($group.Name) from $($group.OwnerNode) to $targetNode..."
    Move-ClusterGroup -Name $group.Name
    Write-Host "Successfully moved $($group.Name)"
}
```

Comment: Add `-Wait 0` to the `Move-ClusterGroup` call to make it return immediately after scheduling the move

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: it works perfect, thanks! The only drawback is: running a loop I know, when failover is done, now I'd probably run some tests and check if it's done..

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a Windows cluster to test with, but I suspect calling `Get-ClusterGroup` should give you the state (eg. whether it's still in the middle of a migration) for each group - write a second loop that goes through the list of groups and waits for the move to be over :)